# Maven error when resolving dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, ehcache

I am new to Maven and am trying to set up one of my first `POM`s. My application will cache using EhCache. Going to Maven Central Repo (link [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.5.0)) I copy-n-pasted the `<dependency>` tag and copy it into my `pom.xml` like so:

```
...many dependencies above this point
<dependency>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
</dependency>
...many dependencies below this point
```

When I save the changes, Eclipse builds the workspace and gives me an error on the opening `<dependency>` tag for EhCache 2.5:

> Missing artifact net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.5.0

So I figured that perhaps v.2.5.0 has something wrong with it, and repeated the same for `2.4.7` (the last `2.4.x` release before `2.5.0`). Same deal.

Since I'm so new to Maven, I don't even know where to begin looking. I tried `Project >> Clean` and even restarted Eclipse to see if it was just a typical Eclipse "quirk". Nope.

I am thinking:

- Could EhCache be publishing bad JARs to the Maven repo?
- Could Maven Repo have something wrong with it?
- Could this be due to something else configured wrong in my `pom.xml`?
- Could this be a "*JAR hell*" issue where I have a conflict somewhere on my dependency graph?

How would SO start tackling this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a way to re-import dependencies in Eclipse? Also check your local repo to see if it's there; maybe try a command-line Maven compile as well. The jar itself is fine; just created a project that uses it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is usually safer to refer to [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org). Dependency from there:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Mind type pom. From module's pom:

> This is a pom artifact to pull in ehcache-core and ehcache-terracotta
>   for clustering. Make sure to set 'type' to 'pom' in your dependency.

Aparently when someone does not need terracotta, ehcache-core will do perfectly fine as other answer states.

Comment: You probably want ehcache-core. ehcache currently is pom parent artifact, that wouldn't really get you what you want.

Comment: @AlexSnaps in fact it does, it's a top-level pom type artifact to pull in jars.

Comment: Yeah, looks like something changed in 2.5 vs. 2.4 apparently. Sorry.

Answer (score 8):

They use `ehcache-core` [in the official documentation](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/hibernate). [Maven Central does not have a jar artifact](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-1719651714) for `ehcache` 2.5 which explains your error message.

Using `ehcache-core` changes the dependency to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Which successfully downloads on my machine (`ehcache` does not).

Comment: Actually this is from pom for ehcache (without -core): This is a pom artifact to pull in ehcache-core and ehcache-terracotta for clustering. Make sure to set 'type' to 'pom' in your dependency.

Comment: @mrembisz you're right, thank you for pointing this out - my analysis was wrong. The dependency however still applies as long as ehcache-core is used without the terracotta stuff. As pointed out, they do it this way in the official ehcache manual.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped this into IntelliJ and it found it.  I suspect there is something wrong with your settings.  Try creating a project with only this dependency in it. If it fails to download, I would check your setting. e.g. `.m2/settings.xml`  Are you using a Nexus server or maven proxy/cache?

BTW: A simpler way to search for JARs is to use http://mvnrepository.com/ which will find all the available versions and show you the XML you need to add.