# EhCache POM is misbehaving

Tags: java, maven, ehcache, ivy, terracotta

Last month I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954093/maven-error-when-resolving-dependency) question because I couldn't get the EhCache jar to pull down into my local Maven cache using the M2E Eclipse plugin.

Now, I am trying to convert several EhCache/Terracotta POM files into Ivy XML files (using the `IvyConvertPom` task (which works perfectly fine for every other POM in my local repository - and there are *hundreds*) and it is choking, stating:

> impossible convert given pom file to ivy file: java.io.IOException: Impossible to load parent for file:/C:/Users/myUser/jars/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache-terracotta-root/2.5.0/ehcache-terracotta-root-2.5.0.pom. Parent=org.terracotta.forge#forge-parent;2.3 from=C:/Users/myUser/jars\net\sf\ehcache\ehcache-terracotta-root\2.5.0\ehcache-terracotta-root-2.5.0.pom to=C:/Users/myUser/jars\net\sf\ehcache\ehcache-terracotta-root\2.5.0\ivy.xml
>   Could not find artifact for C:/Users/myUser\jars\net\sf\ehcache\ehcache-terracotta-root\2.5.0\ehcache-terracotta-root-2.5.0.pom

This is happening for all of the following EhCache/Terracotta artifacts:

- `net\sf\ehcache\ehcache-terracotta\2.4.7\ehcache-terracotta-2.4.7.pom`
- `net\sf\ehcache\ehcache-terracotta\2.5.0\ehcache-terracotta-2.5.0.pom`
- `net\sf\ehcache\ehcache-terracotta-root\2.4.7\ehcache-terracotta-root-2.4.7.pom`
- `net\sf\ehcache\ehcache-terracotta-root\2.5.0\ehcache-terracotta-root-2.5.0.pom`

I'm not sure if this issue is related to the issue I had last month, or if the developers over at EhCache just have a non-standard way of writing their POMs, but this is twice now where Maven (`IvyConvertPom` uses Maven XSLT under the hood) has choked on doing something with their jars.

Does anything jump out at anybody as being obvious? Otherwise I have to debug Ivy code, which sounds like a *painful* way to wrap up a Wednesday. I'll do it if I have to, but thought I'd ask here first in case I was missing something glaring.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the background to this work? Why do you need to convert from Maven to Ivy? I ask because although I'm a big big fan of ivy, my repositories are managed by Nexus (Maven repository manager)

Comment: I am a solo developer on a strict timeline and gave Maven my absolute best shot, but sadly, couldn't get it up and running within the time frame I had set forth for getting my repository/build together. Since I've only used Ivy in the workplace I am already familiar with it. It is clear to me that Maven is a fantastic tool, and some day I hope to completely grasp it, but for now I'm "stuck" with Ivy (which is still great!), which means unless I want to use RoundUp or some other public repo (not an option), or hand-write my own Ivy files (not an option), I need a POM-to-Ivy converter.

Comment: And I know its going 3-sides-around-the-barn here, but its a solution that works...for *every* dependency *except* EhCache!

Comment: You missed my point, I use ivy in my builds as well. On the repository side the files are managed by Nexus. Ivy is able to talk "Maven" :-)  In my opinion this is the best of both worlds. There are a lot of good reasons to use Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that ivy can't resolve org.terracotta.forge#forge-parent;2.3

I'm not expert in ivy or IvyConvertPom, but I think you might need to somehow compel ivy into using the terracotta maven repository:

http://repo.terracotta.org/maven2/

I think I reproduced this problem locally and ran ant with "-d" and I could see it try all the standard maven repos out there, but not all terracotta artifacts are on maven central.

I have no idea how to inform ivy about other repos though, hopefully you know that bit of the puzzle

Answer (score 0):

The ehcache versions prior to 2.9.0 have declared terracotta artifacts as a managed dependency supplied by the specific maven repository.

A fix for this bug has made it to ehcache project on Feb 6, 2015 where it became a jar dependency instead.